# Car has trouble starting ONLY after it has been sitting overnight

Tags: engine, starting, vw, maintenance, polo

I own a Volkswagen Polo 2015, It has clocked around 40000 miles. It has a very peculiar problem, i.e the car has trouble starting only after it has been sitting for 7+ hours. Once the car starts, the starting problem completely vanishes, and the car starts in one crank for rest of the day and runs perfectly fine. No overheating or loss of power.

Every morning I have to crank the car multiple times (8-10) to start the engine, I have noticed the engine starts in almost all of my cranking attempts but engine stalls after reaching 400-500 RPM. It feels like car is suffocating (indeducate fuel or air) I have to give it gas to increase the RPM to 2-4K range then the engine comes to life.

I have also noticed rough idle in the morning starts, I do not notice any roughness in the idle during the day

What I have tried (but did not work) :

- Scanned car for any error codes (there are none)
- Changed oil and fuel filter
- Cleaned throttle body
- Drained old gasoline and refilled with new gasoline
- Tried turning ignition on and off couple of times to make sure fuel pump had enough pressure.

What could be causing this issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: Check your battery voltage before you start in the morning.

Comment: Although it usually sets a code, the coolant temperature sensor could be faulty. Can be checked with a multimeter or scanner.

Comment: Faulty check valve inside fuel pump? Test = turn key to on, wait 15 seconds, then turn key to start.  The check valve prevents fuel from draining out of fuel line between pump and engine. Yours is probably stuck open.

Comment: vacuum leak plugged by sludge that shrinks overnight?